# Select count int type

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have this select where I want to get `id` count:

```
$x = DB::select('   select count(id)
                    from repairs
                    where vehicle_id = ?',
                    [$vehicle->id]);
```

But I am not sure if I am getting in my variable `$x` just a simple int number or some `string` type, because I want to use this `$x` variable in

```
if($x>0){ 
   do something
}
```

And I always get non zero value, even though I should get zero. What is wrong?

Comment: possibly try if($[0]->count >0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your `select` not returning a scale value. and because i don't know your `ORM` i just can tell you try `if(count($x)>0)`

Comment: Oh, so simple, I did not think of this solution.

Comment: yes  and if not works in others cases try to change your query to  `select id from repairs where vehicle_id = ?`

Comment: Yes, I have removed `count` from query.